# json file schema/object to spark schema for loading dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I have to load lots of files to hive tables using pySpark. There is multiple different json files containing data and separate files where file data schemas are defined. When loading files without passing schema, data columns gets out of order that is why i would like to create schemas. Json files looks like:

```
data: {'col1': 'ASDFG', 'col2': 'ASDXC'...

schema: {'description': 'filename', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'col1': {'type': 'string'}, 'col2': {'type': 'string}, 'col3': {'type': 'string} ...
```

My idea is to read this file as dictionary, extract "properties" key values as column names and data types, then SOMEHOW generate schema for spark dataframe load to hive. Is there any other options to it? I would extremely appreciate your help or some examples if any of you ever faced this kind of situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You say they get out of order, but that is because python dicts didn't have order (except most recent versions).

You could use `OrderedDict` instead and they will keep the original order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = json.loads(my_json, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Comment: What I mean by saying getting out of order is that when data is loaded to hive, for example, data that must be in column 1 is is in why different column. I'm passing all data straight to spark dataframe and seems that column name are ordered in way different sequence than it is in file. Thats why i want to create schema, which i would like to pass when loading data to keep everything in place in hive.

Comment: @AdasKavaliauskas how are you loading data in hive? Did you try using OrderedDicts and it didn't work?

Comment: No, i havent tried OrderedDicts. I'm reading json with SparkContext to create dataframe and then writing to hive. Should firstly use json.loads?